# JFrame stops displaying when it previously displayed before

Tags: java, html, swing, jframe, jtextpane

This is a follow on question from [Display and interact with an HTML form in a Swing application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145405/display-and-interact-with-an-html-form-in-a-swing-application). I've copied the code and run it successfully while in Eclipse (Indigo) but for some mysterious reason it's stopped working. I was able to run it several times in a row, but now I'm lucky if I can get it to work at all.

Running it with JUnit under debug, it I've single stepped up to the`javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {` line;  The next step jumps straight to the `System.in.read()` line effectively skipping the display logic.

I suspect its got something to the `invokeLater` method.  From my research, `invokeLater` puts its `Runnable()` on the dispatch queue and the `Runnable` will be run whenever the VM gets around to it.  There's some mention that if a `Runnable()` experiences and exception it won't "unwind", which I assume means that it won't close and will end up blocking the queue. I suspect that one of my invocations has stopped and is clogging the queue but have no idea why or how to clear the queue.

Questions:
Is there any way to clear the queue?  I've stopped and restarted Eclipse several times thinking that would clear the dispatch queue, but no luck.

Is it possible that as far as Java is concerned the `JFrame` **is** displaying, but it's not actually showing up on the screen so I can hit the submit button?  What would cause this?  Why would it work several times in a row, then suddenly stop?

Below is the relavant code.

JUnit stub:

```
@Test
public final void testTestForms()  {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145405/display-and-interact-with-an-html-form-in-a-swing-application
    Navigate n = new Navigate();
    try {
        n.testForms();
        n= null;  // in desperate attempt to garbage collect
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error invoking n.testForms()");
        e.printStackTrace();
        n= null;
    }
    n = null;

}
```

The subject under study:

```
public class Navigate  {
@Test
public void testForms() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("in testForms()");
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("in run()");
            javax.swing.JFrame jf = new javax.swing.JFrame();
            jf.setSize(300, 300);
            jf.setVisible(true);
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
            textPane.setContentType("text/html");
            textPane.setEditable(false);
            textPane.setText("<html>" + "<body>" + "<form action=\"#\">"
                    + "<input name=\"input1\" type=\"text\" />"
                    + "<input name=\"input2\" type=\"text\" /><br/>"
                    + "<input name=\"cb1\" type=\"checkbox\" /><br/>"
                    + "<input name=\"rb1\" type=\"radio\" /><br/>"
                    + "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"go\" />" + "</form>"
                    + "</body>" + "</html>");

            jf.getContentPane().setLayout(
                    new BoxLayout(jf.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            jf.getContentPane().add(textPane);

            HTMLEditorKit kit = (HTMLEditorKit) textPane.getEditorKit();
            kit.setAutoFormSubmission(false);
            textPane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
                public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                    if (e instanceof FormSubmitEvent) {
                        System.out.println(((FormSubmitEvent) e).getData());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
);
    // try to catch exceptions that could plug the queue?
    try {
        System.in.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error with System.in.read()");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
    try {
        finalize();  // another desperate attempt
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` instead??

Comment: @MadProgrammer +1 yup that can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible that as far as Java is concerned the `JFrame` is
>   displaying, but it's not actually showing up on the screen so I can
>   hit the submit button? What would cause this? Why would it work
>   several times in a row, then suddenly stop?

Yes because you call `setVisible(true)` on `JFrame` instance before all components have been added.

There are also other anomalies in your code which could cause problems:

- Dont call `JFrame#setVisible(true)` before all components have been added to `JFrame`
- Dont call `JFrame#setSize(..)` rather call `JFrame#pack()` just before setting `JFrame` visible
- Your `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(..)` should not be nested in the `JFrame` class itself rather make it so that you surround the creation of the `JFrame` instance in `SwingUtilitites.invokeLater(...)`
- Dont call `System.in.read()` this will block the EDT thread and your UI will freeze
- Dont rely on calling a method to create the `JFrame` instance (`testForms()`), make sure the `JFrame` instance is created within the classes constructor.

Here is an exmple I made:

[image]

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;
import javax.swing.text.html.FormSubmitEvent;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class JavaApplication26 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //create new instance of JFrame
                new Navigate();
            }
        });
    }
}

class Navigate {

    public Navigate() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() { //this is a constructor

        javax.swing.JFrame jf = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setContentType("text/html");
        textPane.setEditable(false);
        textPane.setText("<html>" + "<body>" + "<form action=\"#\">"
                + "<input name=\"input1\" type=\"text\" />"
                + "<input name=\"input2\" type=\"text\" /><br/>"
                + "<input name=\"cb1\" type=\"checkbox\" /><br/>"
                + "<input name=\"rb1\" type=\"radio\" /><br/>"
                + "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"go\" />" + "</form>"
                + "</body>" + "</html>");

        HTMLEditorKit kit = (HTMLEditorKit) textPane.getEditorKit();
        kit.setAutoFormSubmission(false);
        textPane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            @Override
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                if (e instanceof FormSubmitEvent) {
                    System.out.println(((FormSubmitEvent) e).getData());
                }
            }
        });

        //add components
        jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(jf.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        jf.getContentPane().add(textPane);

        jf.pack();//pack
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the new example and the suggestions.  Still new at this and just did a simple cut and paste of the code so I could play with it.  
It must be a JUnit thing, because when running your example through JUnit's test stubs, it behaved the same way -- skipped right over the display logic.  Running both my original and your example with a static main() worked consistently everytime.